# RFC 4648 (Base64) Implementation in Python

Tags: python, base64

Is there any implementation of [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) ("The Base16, Base32, and Base64 Data Encodings") in Python?
Note, I am specifically looking for RFC 4648, not its predecessor. Other scripting languages might work as long as it does not take too long. Python is preferred.

Comment: @Amro for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659710/rfc-4648-base16-32-64-implementation-in-matlab :)

Answer (score 2):

Python has a [base64](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) module which implements RFC 3548 (an older revision of RFC 4648).

Comment: In the case of an 8-digit binary number, the last 6-digit group is always zero. hence it is skipped, but I don't find this anywhere in the RFC. Do you know where it is?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you give a specific example?

Comment: for instance, 102=01100110 in binary. following the rules, you should split it into three groups with padding, i.e., 011001 100000 000000. but 000000 is not encoded, and the final result is Zg==

Comment: That's right. The `=` padding characters are used so that the decoder can recover the original length of the data. This is discussed in section 4 of RFC 4648, in the paragraph starting "Special processing is performed if fewer than 24 bits are available...".

Comment: The question specifically says predecessors are no good in this case.

Comment: @EbiDK: Yes, that's true, but that comment was just added today, nearly a year after I had posted this answer. The OP would do well to explain exactly which differences between RFC 3548 and RFC 4648 are important in relation to this question.

Comment: Python even has built-in encoding for strings (but maybe that's internally relayed to the module):  `"adsf".encode('base64')` → `'YXNkZg==\n'`

Comment: Looking at the ['what changed' section](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-13) of the newer RFC, my conclusion is that the Python base64 implementation is compliant. What is missing is a base32 alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby implements RFC 4648 in the `Base64#strict_decode64` and `Base64#strict_encode64` methods.  [Source.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-strict_decode64)

Answer (score 0):

There's a string-operand version of base64 as well:

```
a_str = 'This is a string'
a_str.encode('base64', 'strict')
'VGhpcyBpcyBhIHN0cmluZw==\n'
```

It does the same as base64.b64encode but I thought I'll throw it in there as an option.

## A Patch:

What you're looking for is  "Extended Hex" for the regular base64 module which i remember i installed for a DNSSEC project a while back: http://bugs.python.org/issue16995

Answer (score 0):

While working with https://golang.org/src/encoding/base32/base32.go

I wasn't able to find a python implementation of what RFC 4648 refers to as "Base 32 Encoding with Extended Hex Alphabet"; so i wrote one for python:

https://gist.github.com/graham/d7845f00fce0690b65ab049d52c1ddcb

As far as I can tell RFC 3548 doesn't differ if you use the standard character map, but I wasn't able to find a standard way to use the extended hex alphabet.

Feel free to copy paste, i'll write some tests and create a git repo if people think this is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

i believe this hack will do the trick:

```
base64_url = base64_string.replace("==","").replace("/", "_").replace("+", "-")
```

Both Base64 and Base64url are ways to encode binary data in string form. You can read about the theory of base64 here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64. The problem with Base64 is that it contains the characters +, /, and =, which have a reserved meaning in some filesystem names and URLs. So base64url solves this by replacing + with - and / with _. The trailing padding character = can be eliminated when not needed, but in a URL it would instead most likely be % URL encoded. Then the encoded data can be included in a URL without problems.

Answer (score -1):

The Go standard library has a pretty good [base64 implementation](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/) (as defined in RFC 4648).

---

Relevant source file:

- [base64.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/base64/base64.go)