# RFC 4648 (Base[16,32,64]) Implementation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, encoding, base64

Is there any implementation of [RFC4648](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648) ("The Base16, Base32, and Base64 Data Encodings") in Matlab?

Comment: In R2016B the function [matlab.net.base64encode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.net.base64encode.html) was introduced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MATLAB you can easily use the embedded [Java capabilities](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html). MATLAB ships with the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) library available on the Java classpath. So you can do:

```
str = 'http://stackoverflow.com/q/11659710/';
encoder = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64();
result = char(encoder.encode(str-0))';
```

The output:

```
>> result
result =
aHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL3EvMTE2NTk3MTAv
```